# jQuery - fire event only for top layer

Tags: jquery, html

so let's say I have a div and and img in it. I have added click event for both the div and the img aswell. When I click on the img I only want to fire the click event for the img.

I could do something with e.stopPropagation(), but in the real enviroment I'll have to attach a click event for almost every single element, so I could end up with 10 divs in each other, etc. So I only need to get the element where the mouse is, no parents (or children) and stuff like that.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Edit: Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/uhuto/881/edit

When you click on the top boxes (the two on each other) while there's the "shield" div how do you get the exact element you clicked on *under* the shield?

Comment: Could you [give an example](http://jsfiddle.net) where stopping propagation isn't desirable?

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/uhuto/881/edit

When you click on the top boxes (the two on each other) while there's the "shield" div how do you get the exact element you clicked on _under_ the shield?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.target` to know the actual clicked element -

```
$('div').on('click',function(e){
  var clickedElement = e.target;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **event object**, like:

```
$('#whatever').click(function(event){
  var ev = event || window.event;
  if(ev.target === this){
    //do your thing here
  }
});
```